# Prove that graph of $f$ , $G(f)$ is an affine variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f \in \tau(V)$, $V$ a variety in $\Bbb A^n$. Define

$G(f)=\{(a_1,\ldots,a_{n+1})\in \Bbb A^{n+1} \mid (a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in V$ and $a_{n+1}=f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\} $

Prove that $G(f)$ is an affine variety.

Now first I thaught $G(f)=V(f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-x_{n+1})$ but this is not true then we can express it as $G(f)=(f^{-1}(k)\cap V)\times k$...

How to do this? If $G(f)=V(f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-x_{n+1})$ then it is algebraic and $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-x_{n+1}$ is irreducible too. So it was done but now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that $V=Z(I)$ where $I$ is an ideal of $k[X_1,...,X_n]$ denote $I'$ the ideal of $k[X_1,...,X_{n+1}]$ generated by $I$. $G(f)=Z(I',X_{n+1}-f)$.